# Как склеить элементы массива в один, суммировав некоторое значение, при определенных условиях в js?

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм

Есть массив, где каждый элемент тоже массив:

```
let arr = [
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 100],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 100],
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 400],
  ['apple', '2021-07-06', 100],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 400],
];
```

Необходимо все подмассивы, где совпадают первые два значения, склеить в один, суммировав их третье значение.
То есть, на выходе должен получиться массив где склеены подмассивы с индексами 0 и 2, а также 1 и 4:

```
[
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 500],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 500],
  ['apple', '2021-07-06', 100],
]
```

Comment: Не надо минусить хороший вопрос. В JavaScript нет стандартного способа работать со сложными ключами в словарях. Задача возникает постоянно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сначала посчитать суммы в хэштаблицу (где ключами является объединение некоторых значений) - а затем преобразовать ее обратно в массив (с разбором каждого ключа обратно в значения). Итого два прохода. А точнее, один проход по данным, и один по хэштаблице:

```js
let arr = [
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 100],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 100],
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 400],
  ['apple', '2021-07-06', 100],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 400],
];

const merged = arr.reduce((rslt, [fruit, date, value]) => {
  const key = [fruit, date].join('|');
  rslt[key] = (rslt[key] || 0) + value;
  return rslt;
}, Object.create(null));

const reconstructed = Object.entries(merged).map(
  ([key, value]) => [...key.split('|'), value]
);

console.log(reconstructed);
```

Разделителем в ключе может быть любая подстрока, которая заведомо не будет встречаться в ключевых значениях.

Тот же самый подход может быть применен с любым (≥2) количеством ключевых значений, с массивами объектов (а не только с массивом подмассивов), и т.д..

Comment: Спасибо, алгоритм верный, только не могу понять, как сохранить другие значения подмассива. Пример выше я привел, для простоты описания задачи, по факту у меня есть подмассивы с множеством данных. Результатом выполнения будет новый массив с 4 данными, мне необходимо сохранить все данные

Comment: @Ilya, так на присваивании значения свойству объекта (хэштаблицы) просто группируй в массив (или в другую структуру) - либо выборочно извлекая значения из исходного подмассива, либо добавляя сам исходный подмассив "рядом" с вычисленными значениями.

Comment: @Ilya, то есть, не обязательно же деструктурировать подмассив именно в параметрах - это можно и в теле функции редьюсера сделать, как `const [fruit, date, value] = item;` чтобы далее запоминать референс на подмассив примерно как `rslt[key] = { item, sum: (rslt[key] || 0) + value };`. Это по идее будет более эффективно, чем реструктуризация через rest- и spread-операторы (т.к. структуры по референсу передаются... другими словами, так мы просто таскаем ссылку на исходный подмассив, не создавая лишних промежуточных массивов: создается только маленький группирующий объект).

Comment: Большое спасибо, сработало :)

Comment: Использовать с осторожностью: `['a|b', 'c', 100], ['a', 'b|c', 200]` склеятся вместе. А split в конце неправильно их разберёт.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, верно, и поэтому в ответе (сразу после примера) указано: _«Разделителем в ключе может быть любая **подстрока, которая заведомо не будет встречаться** в ключевых значениях.»_. Это означает то, что в случаях подобных `['a|b', 'c', 100]` такое условие не соблюдается, и надо менять символ-разделитель в соответствии с форматом значений используемых данных (такие вещи на ответственности разработчика, не кода).

Comment: Плохо, когда ошибка обработки данных зависит от самих данных. Приведенный код будет много лет работать правильно, пока в один прекрасный день запрещённый разделитель не уронит всю программу.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, ну, если программа была "написана" методом слепого копипаста примеров из stackoverflow, то она (как и ее разработчик) в полной мере заслуживает такой работоспособности  Справедливость торжествует, естественный отбор в действии - не вижу в этом никакой проблемы. Всем кто считает нужным писать в каждом ответе AI-решение которое будет работать за программиста - предлагаю так и поступать ;)

Answer (score 0):

Нужен ключ из пары значений. К сожалению, `JavaScript` допускает в качестве ключей только строки и числа. Даже `Map` не поможет - он принимает массивы в качестве ключей но сравнивает их не по значению.

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) преобразует массив в строку гарантируя что разные по значению массивы породят разные строки. В словаре хранятся целиком записи (фрукт/дата/значение), не только значения. Фрукт и дату можно было бы восстановить из ключа, я так не делаю, чтобы не добавлять ещё одну сложную операцию:

```js
const merge = a => {
    const map = Object.create(null);
    for (const [fruit, date, value] of a) {
        const key = JSON.stringify([fruit, date]);
        const record = map[key];
        if (record === undefined) {
            map[key] = [fruit, date, value];
        } else {
            record[2] += value
        }
    }
    return Object.values(map);
};

console.log(merge([
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 100],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 100],
  ['orange', '2021-07-01', 400],
  ['apple', '2021-07-06', 100],
  ['apple', '2021-07-01', 400],
]));
```