# Составить самое большое число из массива чисел

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, сортировка

Вечером ребята решили поиграть в игру «Большое число».
Даны числа. Нужно определить, какое самое большое число можно из них составить.
Количество чисел не превосходит 100.
Числа неотрицательные.
Каждое не превосходит 1000.
Нужно вывести самое большое число, которое можно составить из данных чисел.

Пример 1
Ввод
15 56 2

Вывод
56215

Пример 2
Ввод
1 783 2

Вывод
78321

Пример 3
Ввод
2 4 5 2 10

Вывод
542210

Вот написал код, но он не работает как нужно. Возможно слишком заморочено, но ничего проще в голову не приходит, как это еще можно сделать.
Пробовал считать суммы чисел - тоже не проходит.
Какие есть варианты? Уже часов 8 сижу с этой задачей.

```js
/*
  Сортирую вставками, в цикле while в проверке запускаю функцию comparator(),
  в которой сравниваю текущее и прошлое значение.
*/

function getBigNumber(list){
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        const itemToInsert = list[i];
        let j = i;
        while(j > 0 && comparator(itemToInsert, list[j - 1])){
            list[j] = list[j - 1];
            j--;
        }
        list[j] = itemToInsert;
    }
    let result = '';

    list.forEach(({ str }) => 
        result += str)

    console.log(result)
}

/*
  Сравниваю текущее и прошлое число.
  Если числа имеют одинаковую длину - сравниваю их как больше - меньше.
  Если у них разная длина, запускаю функцию compare(), где разбиваю числа на
  массив цифр. Если их первые числа разные, тогда смотрю какое больше больше,
  это и верну как большее. 
  Если первые числа одинаковые, тогда цикл while отрежет первые цифры и
  сравнение продолжится по следующим, while работает пока первые числа одинаковые
  и хоть в каком то массиве больше чем 1 число.
  Затем сравниваю первые числа массивов, где число больше, тот больше. Если в 
  одном из массивов 1 число, а в другом 2, тогда сравниваю первое число с последним.
  Если последнее больше первого - значит оно больше.
*/

function comparator(current, prev){
    const compare = (left, right) => {
        const splittedLeft = left.split('');
        const splittedRight = right.split('');

        while(left[0] === right[0] && splittedLeft.length > 1 && splittedRight.length > 1){
            splittedLeft.shift();
            splittedRight.shift();
        }
        
        if(splittedLeft[0] > splittedRight[0] && splittedLeft.length >= 1 && splittedRight.length >= 1)
            return left;
        else if(splittedLeft[0] < splittedRight[0] && splittedLeft.length >= 1 && splittedRight.length >= 1)
            return right;
        else if(splittedLeft.length < splittedRight.length && splittedLeft[0] > splittedRight[splittedRight.length - 1])
            return left;
        else if(splittedLeft.length < splittedRight.length && splittedLeft[0] < splittedRight[splittedRight.length - 1])
            return right
        else if(splittedLeft.length > splittedRight.length && splittedRight[0] > splittedLeft[splittedLeft.length - 1])
            return right;
        else if(splittedLeft.length > splittedRight.length && splittedRight[0] < splittedLeft[splittedLeft.length - 1])
            return left;
    }

    const splittedCurrent = current.split('');
    const splittedPrev = prev.split('');

    if(splittedCurrent.length === splittedPrev.length)
        return Number(prev) - Number(current) > 0 ? 
            true : false;

    else
        return compare(prev, current) === prev ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решал в своё время на Яве

```
class Solution {
    public String largestNumber(int[] nums) {
        String [] s = new String [nums.length];
        int len=0;
        boolean hasNonZero = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int n = nums[i];
            if (n > 0) hasNonZero = true;
            String t = String.valueOf(n);
            len += t.length();
            s[i] = t;
        }
        if (!hasNonZero) return "0";
        
        Arrays.sort(s, (a,b) -> this.compare(b,a));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (String t : s) {
            sb.append(t);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
    // AB ABY ==> ABABY vs ABYAB
    // AB > ABY if A > Y 
    private int compare(String a, String b) {
        int a_len = a.length();
        int b_len = b.length();
        int len = a_len == b_len ? a_len : a_len + b_len;
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
            char ac = i < a_len ? a.charAt(i) : b.charAt(i-a_len);
            char bc = i < b_len ? b.charAt(i) : a.charAt(i-b_len);
            if (ac == bc) continue;
            return ac < bc ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Переписал компаратор на JS и все прошло, спасибо!

Comment: @Dimitar, поделитесь, пожалуйста, результатом. Можете добавить в этот ответ код JS? Или добавиться собственный ответ?

Answer (score 4):

В общем, я честно пытался придумать нечто изящное, но в итоге все равно пришел к глупому решению без математики:

```js
const foo = str => str.split(/\s+/).sort((a, b) => (b + a) - (a + b)).join('');


console.log(foo('15 56 2'));     // --> 56215
console.log(foo('1 783 2'));     // --> 78321
console.log(foo('2 4 5 2 10'));  // --> 542210
console.log(foo('91 9'));        // --> 991
console.log(foo('23 239'));      // --> 23923
console.log(foo('23 23234'));    // --> 2323423
```

Вроде работает, но удовлетворения решением нет((

Comment: `console.log(foo('23 239'));` --> 23239, а должно быть 23923)) Я тут уже засиделся с этим)) И даже это решаемо быстро, а потом появился `23 23234`

Comment: @Leonid, нублин))

Comment: МЕГАКРАСАВА!!!!! Очень красивое решение. Самое лаконичное и красивое решение.

Comment: @Leonid, лаконичное это да, но решение же на "механическом" переборе вариантов (всю работу делает `sort`, это решение как "черный ящик"), поэтому воспринимаю его некрасивым (всегда завидовал математикам с их особой алгоритмической магией... которую у меня никак не получается освоить). Все равно - спасибо за похвалу

Comment: Функцию сортировки можно и написать самому, но в основе все равно будет компаратор. Эта функция сравнения двух отдельных элементов  - наикратчайший способ, сам алгоритм которого можно было расписать в виде сложной функции. А здесь - работа будет производиться до первого отличающегося символа в обоих случаях. Для ускорения работы всего алгоритма можно произвести быструю сортировку на основе сравнения строк в самом простом виде. А математика здесь не при чем, речь ведь идет о комбинациях представления чисел - это уже лингвистика. Мы составляем слово, которое выражает наибольшее число.

Comment: Скажем, для Римских цифр это не будет иметь ни малейшего смысла. А здесь используется уникальное свойство современного представления чисел с увеличением порядка за счет 0. И двоичное представление чисел, как и работа сумматора, в этом смысле ничем не отличается.

Comment: Как доказать транзитивность такого отношения "больше"?

Comment: @Leonid, _«это уже лингвистика. Мы составляем слово, которое выражает наибольшее число»_ - да, именно. Но мне кажется, что эта задача может быть решена и математическим путем тоже (использованием свойств чисел для вывода формулы, а затем составлением полноценного алгоритма)... такой путь был бы более сложен, но и более показателен, чем делегирование части решения "магии" метода `sort` (внутреннему алгоритму). Другими словами, считаю что программист должен быть способен решать задачи и без помощи магии стандартных библиотек/апи - и (в данном аспекте, с этой задачей) как программист я заfailился

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, она уже доказана практически - т.к. в третья величина присутствует в первых его тестовых вызовах функции (где кол-во чисел в строковом аргументе >2), и _«`compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements `a` and `b` as its two arguments. **If inconsistent results are returned, then the sort order is undefined**»_.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, то есть: при кол-ве сортируемых значений >2, транзитивность доказывается самим компаратором - т.к. он последовательно вызывается для каждой пары из набора сортируемых значений (тем самым реализуя проверку отношения двух величин через вычисление результата отношения с третьей величиной). Показателем успешной проверки (наличия транзитивности отношения) является корректно отсортированный набор значений (см. цитату выше). А если этого показателя мало - то можно либо проследить вычисления компаратора через отладчик, либо добавить в компаратор отладочный вывод (a, b, result).

Comment: Надо доказывать. Без доказанной транзитивности сортировка плохо отсортирует массив.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, так доказана уже. Прочти два предыдущих комментария.

Comment: `a < b & b < c => a < c` - транзитивность. Не вижу где она доказана.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, соболезную, но ничем (помимо уже предоставленного ранее объяснения) помочь не могу.

Comment: https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11, искать `A function comparefn is a consistent comparison function`. Там в требованиях рефлексивность, симметричность и транзитивность.

Comment: _Надо доказывать. Без доказанной транзитивности сортировка плохо отсортирует массив._ - если быстро не посчитать сколько нас на корабле, то корабль утонет?))) Что здесь происходит? Автор тоже не оценил простоты решения...

Comment: @Leonid, в плане претензий к "недоказанной транзитивности" - могу ошибаться, но это по-моему второй эпизод [вот этого сериала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306994/#comment2308325_1307017) (ну вот такая точка зрения на ответы у данного участника, он имеет на нее право). А автор выбрал то решение, которое больше помогло лично ему - так и должно быть, в принятие ответа заложен как раз такой смысл :)

Comment: Сожалею, если доставляю неудобства. Но вопрос о транзитивности интересен и не так прост. "Если быстро не сосчитать сколько нас на корабле, то корабль может утонуть в шторм".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да все нормально - я не против замечаний, только "за". Просто хотелось бы более конструктивных диалогов, где каждый не только высказывается, но и слушает. Вот к примеру, тут было приведено доказательство транзитивности (успешная сортировка), но оно было проигнорировано - хотя логически, сначала это доказательство должно быть опровергнуто, перед тем как делать заявление "надо проверять". А получилось что шаг опровержения был пропущен, и от этого заявление выглядит как попытка навязать мнение. Без обид, но я не понимаю смысла такого подхода (и пресекаю его, зачастую грубо)